# Is there a way to remove hours and add seconds to a UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In my application I want people to be able to select a minute and second  rather than an hour and a minute.

**Is there a way to remove the hours and add seconds as an option for a UIDatePicker?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick review of the documentation and I don't think you can do just minutes and seconds.  After all, this would not really be a Date picker anymore, just a minute/second picker.

Not knowing your app at all, I think you should be able to create your own UIPickerView instance or subclass and configure it with Minutes and Seconds easily enough.

Comment: I didn't realize that was an option. I'm pretty new to iOS development. I'll certainly look into the UIPickerView. Thanks. I think this qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a bit late, but in case anyone else find this I made LETimeIntervalPicker a while ago. It's like a UIDatePicker but with hours, minutes and seconds. https://github.com/ludvigeriksson/LETimeIntervalPicker

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at this for my next project. Also, just so you're aware, people tend to down vote link only answers. You should always try to add some code whenever possible. Thanks for sharing this.